# Oracle 11g. JVM Aurora. JDK 1.6. Ошибка "Сould not generate DH keypair" при подключении по https (ssl)

Tags: java, oracle

Добрый день.

Есть метод java "обернутый" в хранимую процедуру Oracle. Метод создает подключение к https URL (SSL), при этом выдается исключение "Could not generate DH keypair". Т.е. работает Java "встроенная" в СУБД Orcale 11g (jre 1.6).

В обычной java (не встроенной в oracle db) это "лечится" либо заменой "Unlimited Strength policy", либо добавлением JCE провайдера (обычно рекомендуют Bouncy Castle).

А как это делать во встроенной в базу Oracel java?
Пробовал помещать файлы "политики" в `ORACLE_HOME/jdr/jre/lib/security` -- не помогает...
Сверял набор провайдеров в `ORACLE_HOME/jdr/jre/lib/security/java.security` и провайдеров получаемых из `java.security.Security.getProviders()` -- они разнятся.
Это наводит на мысль, что java встроенная в базу Oracle живет по какие-то свои "законам".

Comment: Более внимательное изучение [Introduction to Java in Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chone.htm) добавило понимания. JVM в Oracledatabase действительно существует отдельно от установленной на ОС Java, в том числе и от Java в ORACLE_HOME. Скомпилированные классы, исходники и ресурсы хранятся как объекты базыв самой базе Oracle. Поэтому для добавления библиотеки Bouncycastle в Java_встроенную_в_БД oracle нужно воспользоваться утилитой **loadjava** (входит в набор Oracle Client, устанавливается в режиме установки "Administrator").

Comment: Пробовал загружать последнюю на текущий момент версию _bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar_. На сколько я понимаю, что это эквивалентно добавлению .jar в jre/lib/ext в обычно Java.
После загрузки можно спокойно ссылаться на библиотеку: `import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider;`.
Это дает возможность добавить JCE провайдер "на лету" во время исполнения": `java.security.Security.insertProviderAt(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(),1);`. Делать это надо ДО открытия подключения -- т.е. ДО вызова `HttpsUrlConnection.connect()` или `.getInputStream()`.

Comment: Кстати, если речь идет о простом подключении по порту (через `Socket`), то очень пригодится материал из [Using BouncyCastle for a simple HTTPS query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171802/using-bouncycastle-for-a-simple-https-query).

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, можно даже через socks-прокси так подключаться --- добавив System.addProperty("socksProxyHost", "<host>") и System.addProperty("socksProxyPort", "<port>"). См. [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).
Но использовать этот метод с https-прокси у меня не получилось. Если кто-то знает как или разобрался --- поделитесь, пожалуйста!

Comment: На текущий момент я подключаюсь через HttpsUrlConnection и добавляю провайдер во время исполнения(`java.security.Security.insertProviderAt`). При этом отправить данные в `InpotStream`получается , а при попытки вычитать ответ из `outputStream` возникает ошибка переполнения архива `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Почему -- пока загадка...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, данную проблемы мы с коллегой решили "в обход": написали с использованием jdk 1.8 простенький прокси, который работаетна tomcat-е. Прокси принимает запросы по http, устанавливает с целевым хостом ssl-соединение и передает запросы/ответы.
За основу брали материал отсюда: http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/java_http_web/article04.html